# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U78') dtype('<U78') dtype('<U78'

Tags: python, numpy, subprocess, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I am reading in images from directories and as I loop through file names I get error mentioned in the title. The variable 'imagePath' is the path to image in my local machine. When 'np.fromfile(imagePath)' is removed the code runs, it even will print the image's path, but blows up when I try to read them in with numpy.

```
def getTrainingDataFromFile():
for subdir, dirs, images in os.walk(directory):
    for sub, dirs, images in os.walk(subdir):
        for currentImage in images:
            imagePath = str(os.getcwd() + "/" + sub.replace("./", "") + "/" + currentImage)
            if '.jpg' in imagePath:
                face = np.fromfile(imagePath)
                images.append(face)
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-8-ce35c0ab49e6> in <module>()
----> 1 getTrainingDataFromFile()

<ipython-input-7-ae9589186aa3> in getTrainingDataFromFile()
     16         for sub, dirs, images in os.walk(subdir):
     17             for currentImage in images:
---> 18                 thisImage = str(os.getcwd() + "/" + sub.replace("./", "") + "/" + currentImage)
     19                 if '.jpg' in thisImage:
     20                     face = np.fromfile(thisImage,dtype=np.uint8)
```

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('

Comment: Please show the whole error message including the traceback, not just a piece of it

Comment: `np.fromfile` does not know how to load a jpeg file (or really any common image format) - you want `imageio.imread(imagePath)` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable `images` to store:

1. A list of filenames
2. A list of images

As a result, you end up doing

> "/" + "file1.png"
>   "/" + "your-gravatar.jpg"
>   "/" + [image]

And in the last case, it obviously fails.

Try choosing two different variable names.

Comment: Wow! I need to goto sleep